# RNIap.getProducts(itemSku) returns empty array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, in-app-purchase

I am using the package `react-native-admob`

I created an alpha track of my app and created a managed product on the play console

If I try

```
RNIap.prepare()
```

I get the error

```
RNIap.prepare is not a function. (In 'RNIap.prepare()', 'RNIap.prepare' is undefined)
```

if I try

```
const itemSkus = Platform.select({
  ios: [
    my_product_id
  ],
  android: [
    my_product_id
  ]
});
const products = await RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus);
console.log(products)
```

I get

```
Array []
```

Is there any additional setup I'm missing? This is my first time working with in-app-purchases on react-native

---

I have been following along with [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@abhayg772/implementing-in-app-purchase-in-react-native-application-3798ca2de5bb), but run into problems when I get to `RNIap.prepare()`. My app was using the Expo managed workflow, and is now using the bare workflow. I am still running my app with expo start, because I don't know what else I can do to run it.

Comment: Do you having issue in android or ios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was actually that I had a different bundle id for the app on the Google Play Console than I did in all my files. Expo chose this other bundle id for me as `com.myAppName`.

Because the play console does not allow you to change the bundle id I had to search for `com.myAppName` everywhere in my project and change it to the bundle id I had entered in on the google play console.

`RNIap.prepare()` is apparently not even a function anymore, but it is true that you must publish a release in the Google Play Store before enabling IAP, but you can publish a Beta.

Answer (score 2):

Have you followed these steps in the document [rn-iap](https://medium.com/@abhayg772/implementing-in-app-purchase-in-react-native-application-3798ca2de5bb)? This was the document which i followed and implemnted in app purchase for both android and ios in react native. It explains easily and beautifully. Do check it out.

ps: Even my app is in production and it has succesfull in app purchase

Comment: Sure did, I run into problems once I get to `RNIap.prepare()`

Answer (score 1):

You can't get RNIap.prepare() in android before first release in Google Play Store

Comment: Do you mean that the app has to be published and available for download before I can call RNIap.prepare()? Does that mean there's no way to test it out before releasing the app

Comment: Yes, You couldn't test before release to google play.

Comment: And, if that code is working on ios and the product id is exact then there couldn't be a problem